# How to apply discount on woocommerce subtotal and total on checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We are trying this type of code it changes subtotal but we want to change total according to subtotal without adding any discount field in order table.

```
// define the woocommerce_cart_subtotal callback 
function filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $array, $int, $int ) { 
// make filter magic happen here... 
};       
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: then what's the problem?

Comment: @Reigel subtotal changes as display(text) but not logically with this hook. So, i want to change in total as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're using the wrong hook. That filter is to change the display sub total.

What you need is this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 30 );
function woocommerce_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    // make magic happen here... 
    // use $cart object to set or calculate anything.

    if ( 'excl' === $cart->tax_display_cart ) {
        $cart->subtotal_ex_tax  = 400;
    } else {
        $cart->subtotal = 350;
    }

}
```

above will result to subtotal displayed as 350 or 400, depending on your tax settings but regardless of what products are in cart. Because we are setting subtotal without logic. Add your own logic.

you can also use `woocommerce_after_calculate_totals` using the same concept as above.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 30 );
function woocommerce_after_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    // make magic happen here... 
    // use $cart object to set or calculate anything.

    if ( 'excl' === $cart->tax_display_cart ) {
        $cart->subtotal_ex_tax  = 400;
    } else {
        $cart->subtotal = 350;
    }
    $cart->total = 50;

}
```

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

Comment: @Reigal I want to change in total as well.

Comment: you can get a hint on this file: `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php` about line 1093.

Comment: $cart->total is not working.I set it like  `$cart->total = 350;`

Comment: I see... use `woocommerce_after_calculate_totals` instead of `woocommerce_calculate_totals`

Comment: woocommerce_after_calculate_totals also not working can you give eg. how can we set it properly.

Comment: on `checkout/order-received/172/?key=wc_order_5b59aff1e2233` page price of each product is still the old one not the updated one.