# tax calculation base on Cost rate When checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want Changes to Woocommerce taxes calculation base on Cost rate When checkout Page like that Ex.sale rate is 100, cost rate 90, tax is 18%, Then Calculation is 100+(90+18%)=206.2
I want to Changes WooCommerce Tax Rates source code.

Comment: You should read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You want us to do the work for you, but you should be supplying code and examples of what you tried and what does not work. Regardless, after one Google search I found the following, which might be exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379965/add-custom-tax-value-at-woocommerce-checkout/47381973#47381973

Comment: In case you dont want to apply as fee - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061710/how-to-apply-discount-on-woocommerce-subtotal-and-total-on-checkout modify the logic to your needs